# Installing Glipper on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I just got a new Laptop with ubuntu 20.04

Trying to find the package to install glipper with

apt-cache search glipper

failed.

Is there a way to install it nonetheless? Is there a good alternative in ubuntu 20.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it manually by downloading packages from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS repository:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/glipper/glipper_2.4-6_all.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.23-0ubuntu11.2_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libappindicator/python-appindicator_12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python/python-gconf_2.28.1+dfsg-1.1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pygtk/python-gtk2_2.24.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/keybinder/python-keybinder_0.3.1-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install ./glipper_2.4-6_all.deb ./python-appindicator_12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-gconf_2.28.1+dfsg-1.1_amd64.deb ./python-gtk2_2.24.0-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./python-keybinder_0.3.1-1_amd64.deb ./libappindicator1_12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ./multiarch-support_2.23-0ubuntu11.2_amd64.deb
```

and then launch with `glipper`. Confirmed to work normally at least on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2):

Glipper was [removed from Debian in 2018](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=888700), and thence from Ubuntu also. It had been unmaintained for years, and depended upon obsolete gnome-python, which in turn depended upon Python 2 (now also deprecated).

Attempting to install this software in Ubuntu 20.04 is not recommended.

For a list of current clipboard managers, try `apt search clipboard manager` or the Search feature of your Ubuntu Software application.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04 at the moment works fine `diodon`, it is similar a my old wmcliphist command in WindowMaker, that also was deprecated